# parse array from json

Tags: arrays, json, parsing

I have an ajax function as:

```
                         $.ajax({
                                  url: 'get_days.php',
                                  type: 'post',
                                  dataType:"json",
                                  data: { firstdate: firstdate,
                                        seconddate: seconddate,
                                        frompartofday: frompartofday,
                                        topartofday: topartofday},
                                  success: function (response) {
                                    if(response.status!='wrong'){
                                        
                                        console.log(response.result1);}}});
```

On server side I am setting the response as

```
$response['result1']=$currentRange;
```

where $currentRange is an array. When printing the response using

```
console.log(response.result1);
```

Output in console is

```
['12-19-2022', '12-20-2022']
0:"12-19-2022"
1:"12-20-2022"
length:2
[[Prototype]]:Array(0)
```

Please help me in accessing the element of this array returned by json with array index.

Comment: I would like to add that when I am trying to access the element of the array as  console.log(response.result1[0]);   I am getting error as  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the elements of an array by bracket notation

```
someArray[i]
```

Where `someArray` is an array (in your case `result1`) and `i` is the index (a number) into the array, starting at index 0. For example

```
result1[0] // gets the first element of the array in your response
```

Comment: When I am trying to access the element of the array as console.log(response.result1[0]); I am getting error as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: I'm not sure, can you give me any more details?